# Custom json key in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an as_json method I'm overriding to include an association.

```
 def as_json(options)

     super((options || { }).merge({
         :include => {:otherobject => {:include => :category}}
    }))

 end
```

So this give me json like this

```
 {
      "prop1": "val1",
      "prop2": "val2",
      "otherobject": {"category": {} }
 }
```

I need to adjust the json to look like this because of my processing code.

```
 {
     "prop1": "val1",
     "prop2": "val2",
     "otherobject": { "otherobject": { "category": {} } }
 }
```

I basically need to wrap the data with another key.  How can I do this in rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def as_json(options = {})
  old = super(options.merge({ :include => {:otherobject => {:include => :category}}))
  new = old.slice!(:otherobject)
  new[:otherobject] = old
  new  
end
```